# Travis CI - environment variable key with dot (.)

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

The screenshot tells the problem:

[image]

I've tried adding double quote but still it doesn't work. As you can see, it works when key don't have dot (.)

Comment: you can't use dot in variable name, that's shell limitation. However you can use underscore

Comment: thats unfortunate. Thank you for this, you can post this as your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use dot in variable name, that's shell limitation. However you can use underscore